# Vuetify v-select: Detect hover event and click programtically

Tags: vuetify.js

I have this v-select:

```
<v-select
      @mouseover="focus"
      :items="items"
      outlined
    ></v-select>
```

And I would like for it to be programtically clicked whenever the user hovers the mouse over the element. Looking over the documentation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/ I don't see a way to listen to a hover event or to click the v-select component programtically.

Can this be achieved?

I'm also looking for a way to blur the v-select component after an item has been selected as the border is highlighted blue after selection and I don't want that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<v-select
      @mouseover.native="focus"
      :items="items"
      outlined
    ></v-select>
```

Comment: Cool! That triggers the focus function (which has to be added to the component's methods attribute). But now how do I programatically click on the select again?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to open and close dropdown from v-select on mouseenter and mouseleave, and ended up having to put a `ref` on the element and then call the methods like so:

```html
@mouseenter.native="openDropdown"
@mouseleave.native="closeDropdown"
```

```js
openDropdown() {
  this.$refs.dropdownSelect.activateMenu()
},
closeDropdown() {
  this.$refs.dropdownSelect.blur()
},
```

Log this.$refs.dropdown and you'll see the methods available on it.